# Can you combine a while statement and an If statement together into one line?

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a game where it plays to 10 points to win and you can also win if a player reaches 7 points without the other player receiving any.

I have an if statement inside a while statement and was wondering if there was a way to combine them into one general statement.

I have tried combining them with an extra set of parenthesis on for the if portion as well as tried to change up the and/or boolean values to see if I got those wrong.

```py
while (count1 <= 10 and count2 <= 10):
   if (count1 == 7 and count2 == 0) or (count2 == 7 and count1 == 0):
```

Happy Path: The while and if loops combine into one statement, while still keeping the rules stated in the summary.

Currently: I have tried a bunch of combinations but they all go to an else statement or go beyond the 10 point limit, which tells me that the while parameters are wrong.

Comment: Why would you combine them? They're checking different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
while (count1 <= 10 and count2 <= 10) or ((count1 != 7 or count2 != 0) and (count2 != 7 or count1 != 0)):
```

I'm using following logic laws in here:

`not (a or b) <=> not a and not b`

and

`not (a and b) <=> not a or not b`